# LinqDataSource Exception

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, exception

Ho to catch SQLExecption from Linq Data Source:

```
<asp:LinqDataSource ID="linq_tipo" runat="server" 
ContextTypeName="Linq_Clinica_Veterinaria" EntityTypeName="" 
TableName="tb_tipo_animals">
</asp:LinqDataSource>
```

What the event, I can do that, before Application_Error() raised?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catch exception like this:

```
protected void linq_tipo_Updating(object sender,
        LinqDataSourceUpdateEventArgs e) {
    if (e.SQLException != null)
    {
    //Handle the exception
        e.ExceptionHandled = true;//Set to true as you have handled the exception
    } }
```

Similarly, you can handle Inserted, Deleted, Selecting and other events.

Comment: No....Imaging I have this after LinqDataSource:<asp:DropDownList ID="tipo_animalDropList" runat="server" Width="140px" 
                    AutoPostBack="True" 
                         DataSourceID="linq_tipo" DataTextField="tipo_animal" 
                         DataValueField="codigo_tipo_animal" 
                         ondatabound="tipo_animalDropList_DataBound">
                 </asp:DropDownList> How to catch the mysqlexception? Which control?